# Setting video source depending on screen size triggers "Warning: Prop `src` did not match."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using Next.js and want to dynamically show a video depending on the user screen size. On mobile a portrait video and on the desktop a widescreen video.
But it is not loading the right video on desktop on the first page load and I get the below error message in the console when doing so.

**Error Message:**

```
Warning: Prop `src` did not match. Server: "../videos/
Mobile_2Mbs_v01.mp4" Client: "../videos/Desktop_4Mbs_v01.mp4"
```

**Code:**

```
// Returning the window.innerWidth and window.innderHeight on resize  
const { width, height } = useScreenSizeProvider();

<video playsInline autoPlay muted loop>
  <source
    src={
      width < 768
        ? "../videos/Mobile_2Mbs_v01.mp4"
        : "../videos/Desktop_4Mbs_v01.mp4"
    }
    type="video/mp4"
  />
</video>
```

**Hook to detect screen size changes**

```
export interface Size {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

/**
 * Subscribing to the window screen object and returning the window innerWidth and innerHeight on resize.
 */
function useScreenSize() {
  const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState<Size>({
    width: typeof window !== "undefined" && window.innerWidth,
    height: typeof window !== "undefined" && window.innerHeight,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setScreenSize({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });
    };
    addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    handleResize();
    return () => removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  return screenSize;
}

export default useScreenSize;
```

**Context**

```
// React
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

// Hooks
import useScreenSize from "../hooks/useScreenSize";

// Interfaces
import { Size } from "../hooks/useScreenSize";

const ScreenSizeContext = createContext<Size>(); // { width: 0, height: 0 }

export const useScreenSizeProvider = () => {
  return useContext(ScreenSizeContext);
};

export const ScreenSizeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const screenSize = useScreenSize();
  return (
    <ScreenSizeContext.Provider value={screenSize}>
      {children}
    </ScreenSizeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where are you using these videos from ? Your app is referrring to them as relative paths

Comment: They are in my puplic directory.

Comment: Are they inside any directory inside public folder?

Comment: If they are in public directory just use `/videos/Mobile_2Mbs_v01.mp4`

Comment: thank you for your note `../`or `/` does the same I now changed it but it's not changing my error it still shows the mobile video on desktop as it seems to have the value 0 on the static side generation on server

Comment: are you trying to identify width and height in getServerSideProps or getStaticProps

Comment: It's a custom hook, I wrapped in a Context provider. So none of them. I guess it's static then by default. I can add it to the question if you like.

Comment: I guess problem is that the default state will load the wrong video first. And then it isn't refreshing till you go back and forth on the site.

Answer (score -1):

The source of the mismatch is that you're initialising the `width` and `height` state variables with a condition like `typeof window !== "undefined" && window.innerWidth`. This will return different things when Next.js pre-renders the page on the server, and when the page gets hydrated on the client - thus triggering the warning.

You should initialise `width` and `height` to a fixed value instead.

```js
const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState<Size>({ 
    width: undefined, 
    height: undefined 
});
```

You should also modifying the video logic to only display once the screen width is known. This prevents the video always showing the same source.

```js
const Index: NextPage = () => {
    const { width } = useScreenSizeProvider();

    return width ? (
        <video playsInline autoPlay muted loop>
            <source 
                src={
                    width < 768 
                      ? "../videos/Mobile_2Mbs_v01.mp4" 
                      : "../videos/Desktop_4Mbs_v01.mp4"
                } 
                type="video/mp4"
            />
        </video>
    ) : (
        <div>Loading Video...</div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that gets rid of the `Warning: Prop `src` did....` but it doesn't fix the problem that the video that is shown is always `"../videos/Desktop_4Mbs_v01.mp4"` doesn't matter what screen size.

Comment: ok looking forward for your updated answer

Comment: @BenjaminK I've updated my answer to only render the video when the screen width is known. Here's a condesanbox implementing the solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cache-72bujz.